# Joby ballhead screw size

Tags: gorillapod

Does anyone know what kind of screw size (diameter) has the Joby Ballhead 1k https://joby.com/ballhead-1k on the BOTTOM of it? Same diameter as the top screw, or larger diameter? I can't find any picture of it from the bottom nor any information about it in the specs.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the [Link](https://joby.com/gorillapod-1k-stand) of the Gorillapod, that the ballhead is designed for, you'll find, that it has a 1/4" standard mount.

Therefor, yes. The bottom is the same as the top

Comment: Could we clean this up and make it a stronger answer? Without the "click on the link" bit. Just a more direct explanation and if possible a link to and a quote from the referenced page for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: A good answer should feature the research/reasoning behind the answer given. Seeing, that I simply visited the Link provided by th OP, immediately saw the Link to the Gorilla pod, visited the page and got the Info from there, I state this as a source. Adding the link itself would have been wise, I added that. Otherwise I see nothing wrong with the structure of the answer

Comment: @MTTI You'll see a lot wrong with it, and so will everyone else, when the link is dead for any one of a variety of reasons.

Comment: As Michael stated, linked content can and often will go dead at one point or another. At which point, the answer is effectively moot. Please also quote the relevant information here in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [product page for the ballhead](https://joby.com/ballhead-1k) states:

> Evolved Design: Removable mini ball head can be used on GorillaPod 1K or standard tripod with ¼"-20 mount.

Therefore the threaded socket is ¼"-20.